# datetime.datetime.strptime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").timetuple().tm_hour

Tags: python, datetime

Here, you can see my code :

```
import datetime
DateS = datetime.datetime.strptime('30/03/2019 00:00:00',"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").timetuple().tm_hour
DateR = datetime.datetime.strptime('15/09/2019 00:00:00',"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").timetuple().tm_hour
ETP=ET0.copy()
for i in range(8760):
    if i >= (DateS - 1) and i <= (DateR - 1) :
       ETP[i] = ET0[i] * DB2.Kc[0]
    else:
       ETP[i] = ET0[i] * DB2.SolNu[0]

ETP[0] = 0
```

I want to get:
Date S = 2136 (day89 * 24hour = 2135)
Date R = 6192 (day258 * 24hour = 6192)

But I get:
Date S = 0
Date R = 0

When I use:

```
DateS = datetime.datetime.strptime('30/03/2019-00:00:00','%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S').timetuple().tm_yday
DateR = datetime.datetime.strptime('15/09/2019-23:00:00','%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S').timetuple().tm_yday
```

I get:
Date S = 89
Date R = 258

But I would like to get the 'hour step time'...

I try different `datetime` with `strptime` and `timetupl` but I never success.

Comment: What do you mean by **hour step time**?

Comment: @Anwarvic Thank you for your question if that can clear up the problem.
I would like to have DateS in hour ie DateS = 2136,  instead of DateS in day where DateS = 89.

Answer (score 0):

try this code with `tm_yday` instead of `tm_hour`

```py
DateS = datetime.datetime.strptime('30/03/2019-00:00:00','%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S').timetuple().tm_yday * 24
DateR = datetime.datetime.strptime('15/09/2019-23:00:00','%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S').timetuple().tm_yday * 24
```

and you will have the output you ask for.